# Are these 3 redirect rules equal?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect the non-https and non-www versions my domain to the https and www version of it. I'm a bit confused by the options. Are these redirect rules equal for my purpose?

```
#  REDIRECT (non-HTTPS or non-WWW) TO HTTPS and WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# Are the following 3 rules equal in effect?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: Far simpler: `RedirectPermanent / https://www.example.com` in the `www.example.com:80` `VirtualHost` block. `mod_rewrite` is a great tool but far too much for simple redirections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`
>    2. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`
>    3. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

These 3 rules are essentially the same and will do the same job in most situations, however, #1 is arguably "better" as it canonicalises a FQDN (where the hostname ends in a dot) and would therefore be the preferred version. (Assuming you have no other directives that do this.)

In a `.htaccess` context, where the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root then #2 and #3 are identical. (However, in a *server* or *virtual host* context then #2 is technically incorrect, as it would result in a double slash after the hostname.)

If the `.htaccess` was located in a subdirectory then rule #2 would not be correct as it would omit the subdirectory from the redirect. Either #1 or #3 (that use `REQUEST_URI`) would be required here.

All 3 versions (together with the `RewriteCond` directive) assume you have no other subdomains, since anything other than `www.` is redirected.

> 1. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

- There is no need for a capturing subpattern (denoted by the surrounding parentheses) in the regex if there is no backreference (eg. `$1`) in the *substition*. You are using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead.
- The regex `.*` could also be simplified and made more efficient, since you don't need to match anything, you just need to be *successful* for *everything*. The regex `.*` traverses the entire URL-path and matches everything. Whereas a regex like `^` simply asserts the start-of-string, so is immediately successful without actually matching anything.
- The order of the flags `L` and `R` do not matter. However, for consistency, I always include the `L` (`last`) flag *last*.

In other words:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I really appreciate the effort to help us learn, than just providing a solution.